# what is the equivalent windows key sequence for the task switicher key on the k350?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wireless-keyboard

I have a Logitech K350 cordless keyboard with several extra keys that can be customized.  On the lower left side it has a key with three overlapping windows on it which brings up a really cool display of all the executing programs, and it extends across all monitors.  This is not alt-tab or windows-tab.  I cannot determine what 'regular' key combination this sends to windows.  I am running windows7. Searching the internet has not provided any help.  The logitech support site says I can reprogram this key, but I just want to know what the default key sequence is.

Comment: It may be a function of the driver and associated software, rather than a Windows function, and hence not duplicable.

Answer (score 0):

The [user guide for the Logitech K350](https://download01.logitech.com/support/24508.1.0.pdf) describes that button as "Windows Vista Flip 3D". That would be <kbd>Win + Tab</kbd> in Windows 7.

You say that it is not <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Win + Tab</kbd> for you, so perhaps the key has already been reprogrammed. If you can provide a screenshot or photo of what you are seeing, perhaps someone will recognize it.